# Magento 2.1.2 - Product Backend EAV Attribute Field Enabled or Disabled Depends on Product Status

Tags: magento2, backend, knockoutjs, data-provider

I have added an EAV attribute named `disabled_date`. I would like to attach an observer to the attribute field on product page where it is disabled if product status is `enabled` (1) and enabled if product status is `disabled` (2).

I have tried using product form modifier:

```
$path = $this->arrayManager->findPath('disabled_date', $meta, null, 'children');
$meta = $this->arrayManager->merge($path . static::META_CONFIG_PATH, $meta, [
    'imports' => [
        'disabled' => '!${$.provider}:data.product.status:value',
    ],
]);
```

The target field is always enabled because product status is always true (product enabled = 1, product disabled = 2).

I also have used these approach and it did not work.

```
'disabled' => '${$.provider}:data.product.status:value == 2'
'disabled' => '${$.provider}:data.product.status:value == 2 ? true : false'
```

Is there any other way to achieve this condition?